# Should we have a chat box linking to the Symposium?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Many custom pages like [SciFi & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) have chatrooms permanently linked directly in their sidebar.

As not many of you will remember, we actually do have a general chatroom in philosophy as well: [The Symposium](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/538/the-symposium)

Especially considering the apparent need for philosophical discussion and clarification that cannot be handled in questions, answers, or comments:

### Should we try to get a direct link to The Symposium in our sidebar as well?

Comment: I had no idea that room existed, I think this is a good idea.

Comment: ditto, I think its a good idea too.

Comment: Excellent idea : the question/ answer format is not ideal for all exchanges.